# Call delete function from controller with ajax in symfony 3

Tags: ajax, symfony, bootstrap-table

[image]I am relatively new to symfony. I have a view page with [bootstrap tables](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/). I also have crud controller (src\AppBundle\Controller\SiftscienceTrackerController.php) created and the delete function is as follows:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, SiftscienceTracker $siftscienceTracker)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($siftscienceTracker);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($siftscienceTracker);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_siftsciencetracker_index');
}
```

My question is whether I can call this function of the controller with ajax call from a delete button in a table row and how ajax should be written? If not can I create another function inside that controller and that one to be called with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jQuery:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, SiftscienceTracker $siftscienceTracker)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($siftscienceTracker);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($siftscienceTracker);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();

     if($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || $request->get('_xml_http_request')){
         return new JsonResponse("{url: $this->generateUrl('admin_siftsciencetracker_index')}", 200);
     }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_siftsciencetracker_index');
}
```

As you can see i check if the request is an ajax request to avoid making a separate action.

Since your action returns a redirection you just return the url as json to the script that made the ajax call and make the redirection in javascript:

```
$.ajax({
   url: $('#my-form').prop('action');
   method: 'post',
   data: $('#myForm').serializeArray() 
   success: function(response){
     window.location(response.url);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I see the logic but I m bit confused with url: $('#my-form').prop('action');. I dont have a form in the view just a table with a row. Question edited with image